# Don't Execute Nx's Router Navigation When Coming From Specific Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx, ngrx-effects, nrwl

In my Angular app I use NgRx and Nx's Router Navigation:

```
@Effect() navigation$ = this.dataPersistence.navigation(A_Component, {
    run: (a: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
        const id = a.params.id;
        if (id) {
            return new SampleAction(State.VIEW, id);
        } else {
            return new SampleAction(State.NEW);
        }
    },
    onError: (a: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, e: any) => {
        console.error(e);
        return null;
    },
});
```

My routes are defined as follows:

```
// ...
RouterModule.forChild([{
        path: 'configurator',
        component: FooComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [{
            path: '',
            component: A_Component
        }, {
            path: 'b',
            component: B_Component,
        }, {
            path: 'c',
            component: C_Component,
        }, ],
    },
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'configurator'
    },
]),
// ...
```

`FooComponent` has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to show one of the 3 components `A_Component`, `B_Component` or `C_Component`.
So when a user navigates to `configurator/`, `FooComponent` shows `A_Component` and the `SampleAction` is triggered. That's fine.

**But:** When a user navigates from either `configurator/b` or `configurator/c` back to `configurator`, the `SampleAction` should **not** be triggered.

How could I do that?